# Authorization Header missing in HTTP POST

Tags: java, python, http, networking

I have an application written in Java to send HTTP POST requests to a specific hostname. This does not seem to work.

I do exactly the same thing in Python, and it works.

The Authorization header seems to be missing when analyzing using curl.

I explicitly supply the authorization both programs. (basic auth)

Asking for advice here without giving away too much (it's a work related project).

*could* this be a network issue? Or an environment issue? Or something within the python requests method that has a default attribute that Java might not have to make that work and not the Java?

Apologies if it's only a vague description but wondering if anyone else has had this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a Java question or a Python question???

Comment: "I have an application written in Java to send HTTP POST requests to a specific hostname. This does not seem to work." - that's simply not enough information for us to help you with your Java part. Show us the code. Ideally a minimum example of the problem without irrelevant pieces.